# How to replace dynamic element in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

In my app, I use a dynamic component. To insert it I call `onTooltipVisible`, where I pass `HTMLDivElement` as a parameter, like this:

```
<div id="tooltip-container"></div>
```

it's a parent inside which I need to insert my component so that my component goes to the shadow-root

```
<div id="tooltip-container">
  #shadow-root(open)
    ...
</div>
```

but when I change something and then `removeTooltip()` has called, this func remove from DOM not only `#shadow-root` with my Component, but the whole parent container, so that on the next steps I can't insert my component again, cause there no parent anymore.

So my question is, how can I remove only this shadow-root and leave parent, or maybe there are some method to replace it again to empty div with `id="tooltip-container"`?

Now my code looks like this:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.removeTooltip();
}

onTooltipVisible(container: HTMLDivElement): void {
  if (container) {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TooltipComponent);
    this.tootipComponentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector, [], container);
    this.applicationRef.attachView(this.tooltipComponentRef.hostView);
  } else {
    this.removeTooltip();
  }
}

removeTooltip(): void {
  if (this.tooltipComponentRef) {
    this.applicationRef.detachView(this.tooltipComponentRef.hostView);
    this.tooltipComponentRef.destroy();
  }
}
```

Would be really grateful for any help!

---

Update:

If I add one more container beetwen my componet and parent everything works

```
onTooltipVisible(container: HTMLDivElement): void {
  if (container) {
    const componentContainer = document.createElement('div');
    container.appendChild(componentContainer);
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(TooltipComponent);
    this.tootipComponentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector, [], componentContainer);
      ...
   }
}
```

But I'm not sure that it's a good solution

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm not sure that it's a good solution

I ran into the same problem. The `ComponentRef.destroy` also destroys the host container, so by creating a child node and use that as the host the original parent container remains intact.

Hence, definitely a good solution from my point of view.